# .img file mounted, want to see file updates without having to remount

Tags: mount, usb, raspberry-pi, loop-device, usb-otg

I have a raspberry pi that is emulating a mass storage device, while having the backing .img file mounted. Once the pi is powered up and the .img is mounted, I turn on the mass storage emulation. I'm following along with [this guide](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive).

I'd like to be able to see new files and file updates on the backing storage without having to remount it (ideally, also without having to "eject" it). I'm trying to write some functionality that will react to new files being written to the emulated mass storage device. I've found that if I mount the emulated mass storage device on my computer and write a file to it, the file is preserved across software "ejects" on the raspberry pi side--but the contents of the mounted backing store .img file do not change until I unmount and remount it.

Is there any way to configure the raspberry pi so that I can easily inspect what's being written to the device? Or is there some sort of limitation on this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

> I've found that if I mount the emulated mass storage device on my computer and write a file to it, the file is preserved across software "ejects" on the raspberry pi side--but the contents of the mounted backing store .img file do not change until I unmount and remount it.

That would probably be because the write operation is cached by the system that is mounting the emulated storage and not written until a) enough time passes, or b) you force the write by using `sync` or `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/sd<emulated storage>` or by unmounting the emulated storage.

USB storage can be quite slow, so writeback caching can provide significant performance advantage: if something is updated several times in quick succession, the later updates can override the older versions in the cache and only the latest version needs to be actually written from the cache to the storage.

If you make a software eject on the RasPi side without first flushing on the computer side, then wait a while (so the cache will attempt to write itself out to the emulated storage), you might find in the computer's `dmesg` output that the computer-side USB storage driver is deeply unhappy about the emulated storage being suddenly non-responsive. But the kernel and drivers are trying not to lose any data, so they will hang onto the cached data in the hopes that the device will reconnect, unless the device is non-responsive for so long that all attempts to write it will time out.

Comment: Forgot to mention but I have been running sync calls on the pi side while the pi is still connected. In the scenario that I'm developing for, the pi will always be connected and there will be new files written maybe once a day. I need to eventually react to them on the pi side.